# Cannot pan gesture smaller UIView outside of its superview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a `UIView` that contains many `UIView` subviews. When the user tries to pan gesture one of the subviews, I want them to be able to drag it anywhere else on the screen.

However, I can only drag these smaller views within the bigger `UIView` they are contained in. When the user first tries to pan gesture the smaller view, is there any way to programmatically create a second UIView on top and then drag around the second UIView instead? The second UIView would be completely new from the smaller view that was first touched.

This is the handler function I have so far, just for reference. I don't know where I would programmatically create the second UIView, though. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
 @objc func handlePanGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    // get translation
    var translation = sender.translation(in: view)
    sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: view)

    // drag around current UIView
    var newView = sender.view as! UIView
    newView.center = CGPoint(x: newView.center.x+translation.x, y: newView.center.y+translation.y)
    newView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
    newView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {
        // add something you want to happen when the Label Panning has started
    }

    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended {
        // add something you want to happen when the Label Panning has ended
    }

    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.changed {
        // add something you want to happen when the Label Panning has been change ( during the moving/panning )
    } else {
        // or something when it's not moving
    }
}
```

[image: What I'm trying to do in my app]

Comment: A picture or video may help others understand what you're trying to do. If you want to move a view outside of its parent view, you would either have to turn off `clpsToBounds` or move the view to a different parent view.

Comment: @shim Added image explaining problem. How would I programmatically change the parent view of the `UIView`?

Comment: removeFromSuperview, addSubview

Comment: @shim when the user first tries to pan gesture the smaller view, is there any way to programmatically create a second UIView and then drag around the second UIView instead? The second UIView would be completely new from the original smaller view that was first touched...

Comment: You could make a view that looks the same and put it in the same initial spot and hide the original one

Comment: And how would I make sure the translations get applied to that second created UIView and not the original gesture recognizer?

Answer (score 1):

A very common pattern that enables dragging of views outside of their superview, is to create a snapshot or clone of the original view as soon as the gesture begins, you can of course hide the original view so to the user it feels like the same UI element is being dragged. It's a pattern used by Apple in their drag and drop sample code here

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop/adopting_drag_and_drop_in_a_custom_view

Have a look at line 36 in ViewController+Drag.swift for the relevant code.

Comment: Is it possible to create this clone of the original view with UIPanGesture? For this project I have to work with a lower iOS deployment target that doesn’t yet have UIDragInteraction

Comment: Yes, it does not depend on the DragAndDrop API at all

Comment: I need to deploy on iOS 10.0, but when I downloaded the sample project on that link I got the error message "'UIDragInteraction' is only available on iOS 11.0 or newer". Where in the pan gesture handler could I make a copy of the view I'm trying to drag?

Comment: On gesture began, then in changed you should also update the translation, you'll need to update the frame on the clone view.

Comment: How would I change `var translation = sender.translation(in: view)` to the programmatically created view's translation? Basically how would I keep the original view exactly where it is and then instead apply all the translations to a newly created view? Would I need 2 handler functions?

Comment: I was able to successfully add a second UIView in .begin, but in .changed I don't know how to change the new view's center if the translation is set to the original view

Comment: You'll need to convert the translation so that it is stated in terms of the new view and it's super view. Have a look at for UIView's convert functions. Also good to think a head, what will you do at the end of the drag? Will this gesture be part of a transition to another view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199816/discussion-between-audrey-ha-and-glotcha).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to be able to drag the smaller views anywhere while maintaining the same layout I have right now

Because of the way touch works, it is impossible by default  for a view to be touched when it reaches the boundaries of its superview. But you can overcome that limitation by overriding `hitTest` in the superview.

Comment: Is there any way to programmatically create a second UIView on top of everything and then drag around the second UIView instead? The second UIView would be completely separate from the original smaller view that was first touched